# Mininet install failed: unable to connect to github.com

Tags: ubuntu, mininet

I am trying to install mininet 2.3.0 on my Ubuntu machine and i get this following error message:

```
root@Mininet-PC:/home/mininet# mininet/util/install.sh -a
.
.
.
Cloning into 'openflow'...
fatal: unable to connect to github.com:
github.com[0: 140.82.121.4]: errno=Connection timed out
```

I tried to ping to github.com at 140.82.121.4 as shown above and i got 0% package loss

When i try to open a simple topology i get this error message:

```
root@Mininet-PC:/home/mininet# mn
*** Creating network
*** Adding controller
*** Adding hosts:
h1 h2 
*** Adding switches:
Cannot find required executable ovs-vsctl.
Please make sure that Open vSwitch (openvswitch.org) is installed and available in your $PATH:
(/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/usr/games:/usr/local/games:/snap/bin)
```

I tried installing `openvswitch-testcontroller` and when i do i get the following wrror message:

```
*** Adding controller
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Caught exception. Cleaning up...

Exception: Please shut down the controller which is running on port 6653:
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:6653            0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN      5982/ovs-testcontro 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
*** Removing excess controllers/ofprotocols/ofdatapaths/pings/noxes
killall controller ofprotocol ofdatapath ping nox_corelt-nox_core ovs-openflowd ovs-controllerovs-testcontroller udpbwtest mnexec ivs ryu-manager 2> /dev/null
killall -9 controller ofprotocol ofdatapath ping nox_corelt-nox_core ovs-openflowd ovs-controllerovs-testcontroller udpbwtest mnexec ivs ryu-manager 2> /dev/null
pkill -9 -f "sudo mnexec"
*** Removing junk from /tmp
rm -f /tmp/vconn* /tmp/vlogs* /tmp/*.out /tmp/*.log
*** Removing old X11 tunnels
*** Removing excess kernel datapaths
ps ax | egrep -o 'dp[0-9]+' | sed 's/dp/nl:/'
***  Removing OVS datapaths
ovs-vsctl --timeout=1 list-br
/bin/sh: 1: ovs-vsctl: not found
ovs-vsctl --timeout=1 list-br
/bin/sh: 1: ovs-vsctl: not found
*** Removing all links of the pattern foo-ethX
ip link show | egrep -o '([-_.[:alnum:]]+-eth[[:digit:]]+)'
ip link show
*** Killing stale mininet node processes
pkill -9 -f mininet:
*** Shutting down stale tunnels
pkill -9 -f Tunnel=Ethernet
pkill -9 -f .ssh/mn
rm -f ~/.ssh/mn/*
*** Cleanup complete.
```

I also tried `apt-get update/apt-get upgrade` still no luck.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this as well, I modified the file ./mininet/util/install.sh to use https instead of git and then it worked.

git clone git://github.com/mininet/mininet.git
to
git clone https://github.com/mininet/openflow.git

Wondering why it wasn't fixed, I then looked at the repo and it looks like they fixed it in the more recent releases of mininet. The problem we both fell into was we followed the directions at http://mininet.org/download/ for the Option 2: Native Installation from Source and it suggests using an older 2.3.0 version.

You could also fix it by just checking out the more recent branch:
git checkout -b mininet-2.3.1b1 2.3.1b1
instead of
git checkout -b mininet-2.3.0 2.3.0